# Any way to set MathJax defaults for the whole browser?

Tags: google-chrome, default-settings, mathjax

I want [MathJax](https://www.mathjax.org) to render using the "Common HTML" method rather than "HTML-CSS".

This is easy enough to change on a per-site basis, but it gets annoying.

Is there any way to change the default across the entire browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  The settings are stored in a browser cookie, and those are tied to specific sites.  There are no global settings that can be used across sites.  Unfortunately, you have to make the setting on each site by hand.